# How can I deploy a Vue.js app on a tomcat?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, vue.js

I have a vue.js application and I want to deploy it on a server on a tomcat, it's posible and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can, an extended tomcat app server has a structure like this:

[it is supposed that you are going to deploy a static application into tomcat]

apache-tomcat-x.y.zz/
    
bin/
    
conf/
    
lib/
    
logs/
    
temp/
    
webapps/
    
work/
    
....

just create a folder in weapps folder[e.g test] and put your static files inside it[just remember to take care of your relative path of resources], then fire up tomcat and in your browser refer to a link like this: http://localhost:8080/test/your_index_file.html

However there is point with is worth mentioning, actually tomcat is a web server[to be more precise it's a servlet container which is used to deploy java web applications into it], you should use a http sever somethig  like apache_http_server or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

The diferente is that in tomcat your application will have a context. 
So, let's suppose that "app-name" in the context of your application inside tomcat.

1o - Create a VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH = '/app-name/' variable in the **.env.prod** file. ("prod" is the default name for production environment)

2o - create a  vue.config.js in root of the project and configure the publicPath

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH
};
```

3o - In the router configuration file, define the base url for the same value

```
let router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH,
    ...
}
```

4o - execute **"npm run build:prod"** command (to load the production environment values)

5o - rename the **"dist"** directory generated by npm to **"app-name"**

6o-  Copy "app-name" to apache-tomcat-x.x.xx/**webapps** dir.

7o-  At last, access: http://url:port/**app-name**. If the Vue application is in localhost 8080 port, access http://localhost:8080/app-name.