# 404 error in Vue.js project during 'npm build' and serve in Apache Tomcat

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs2, vue-router

I created a Vue.js project with following configuration in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.5",
    "vee-validate": "^3.3.7",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-sanitize": "^0.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
```

I can test the project at the url http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/test after running `npm run serve`.

However, when I built the project with `npm run build` and moved the dist folder to Apache Tomcat, I get a 404 error for the url http://127.0.0.1:8080/vue/test/test (vue is the folder where the dist contents are placed).

I checked the browser console and see the following error.

> GET http://localhost:8080/vue/test/test [HTTP/1.1 404  5ms]

Here is the router configuration.

```
export default new Router({
mode : 'history',
base: '/vue/',
routes : [
        {
            path : '/:param1/:param2',                
            name : 'comp1',
            component : comp1,
            props : true
        }
      ]})
```

**Update:** I also followed the steps described in this answer to set a base path in the Router, but it still doesnt work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60635441/6352160
How can I debug this error? Why would the same code fail on `npm run build` and deploy, but work on `npm run serve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually create a `web.xml` file to the folder `webapp/vue/WEB-INF/` (also create WEB-INF ) with following content:

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1" metadata-complete="true">
  <display-name>Router for Tomcat</display-name>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

restart tomcat

Comment: what should be the value for 'publicPath:' in vue.config.js? I added web.xml and I tried '' and '\', but it still gives same 404 error.

Comment: @ShankarPS @ShankarPS In your case, the value for `publicPath` should be `vue`, make sure the `index.html` is directly in `vue` folder, not in it's any sub directory, also check tomcat configuration file `server.xml` which is at `path_to_tomcat/conf/`, for simplicity, don't change it, leave it as it was when initially installed.

Comment: Nice. You should consider opening a PR for https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations to add an example for Tomcat